# como insertar el resultado de una condición en una nueva columna Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Yo tengo la siguiente estructura de un df

```
{ct: [000099,00090], date: [12-12-2020, 12-11-2020], price: [4, 5], type: [debit, credit]}
```

Yo leo el .txt, y todo, creo la columna, pero los valores me retornan en nan.

Mi codigo

```
import pandas as pd

file= "C:\\....\\data.txt"

columns=("ct", "date", "price", "type")
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="|", names=columns)
df.loc[:, 'dbts']=df[df['price']>0 & df[df['type'] != 'credit']
print(df)
```

quiero asignar los valores del campo 'price' a la nueva columna 'dbts', si cumplen con la condición
Agradecido con sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero esta solución:

Construí todo para poder correr el ejercicio (quité los ceros extras de la izquierda en `ct` y las fechas las ordené de `yyyy-mm-dd` solo para fines ilustrativos)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ct': [99,90], 'date': ['2020-12-12', '2020-11-12'], 'price': [4, 5], 'type': ['debit', 'credit']}

#Construyo el dataframe. Es diferente al tuyo porque no tengo acceso a tu csv pero tu solución es correcta.
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Aquí en lugar de usar loc puedes ir directo a crear la columna e integrar el resultado, date cuenta que al final agregué `['price']` para devolver el valor que te interesa:

```
df['dbts'] = df[(df['price']>0) & (df['type'] != 'credit')]['price']
```

Produce:

```
print(df)

   ct        date  price    type  dbts
0  99  2020-12-12      4   debit   4.0
1  90  2020-11-12      5  credit   NaN
```

Comment: Te lucistes hermano, muchisimas gracias <3